# Cant access NUXT routes when hosted through pm2 and apache proxypass config

Tags: apache, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, pm2, proxypass

I have setup working nuxtjs ssr app using pm2 on the vps linux cloud. Its works well on the localhost. For the online deployment, I use pm2 to get the app running. The app is accessible through the domain address. But the issue is with the routes, for example I have set the address as : [www.someurl.com/ssrapp](http://www.someurl.com/ssrapp) , the apache uses proxypass to map the /ssrapp to the www.localhost:3000/ address. But after the app page loads, it says /ssrapp route not found. I can see this issue could be with mapping done in the apache proxypass. But how to configure this part? I cant use nginx ,so can only proceed with apache setup for this.

Comment: I'm not sure about the extra proxypass, isn't this enough? https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/pm2

Comment: The pm2 helps with running and managing the js app. I need either nginx or apache to direct the domain to the localhost:port where the app is running. So I use proxypass from apache to do this.